# autoloading in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, production-environment, rails-api, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have all my controllers declared as a

`class Api::V1::SomeController < Api::V1::ApiController; (...); end`

where

`class Api::V1::ApiController < ApplicationController; end`

All my controllers are placed in `/app/controllers/api/v1/*_controller.rb`, `ApplicationController` is under `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`.

On development everything works fine, but I have problem with requiring and loading controllers wrapped in api versioning namespace in production.

In production environment (locally or heroku) I got: `LoadError (Unable to autoload constant Api::V1::SomeController, expected /app/app/controllers/api/v1/some_controller.rb to define it):`

What is the correct way to configure `app/config/environments/production.rb` and require versioning api on production environment.

Comment: Can you share the error stacktrace in the question.

Comment: FYI this really isn't a Heroku issue, it's a "production environment" and Rails auto loading issue. See my answer, below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you'll get around this issue by taking a modular approach to defining all of your namespaced classes. For example:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class SomeController < ApiController
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

And:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class ApiController < ::ApplicationController
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

Using this pattern disambiguates the namespaces for autoloading in Rails. Autoloading is a fairly complex mechanism... (And does seem to behave differently between development and production!) If you'd like to learn more of the inner workings [this article](http://urbanautomaton.com/blog/2013/08/27/rails-autoloading-hell/) is well worth the read.

**UPDATE**

The `::` in `::ApplicationController` means "with no namespace" or the "default namespace". That part is probably not needed in this case since you probably only have one `ApplicationController` constant defined.

The difference this approach creates is that it ensures that Rails will not "skip over" your constant definition, so to speak. The article I linked above explains it by example.

Comment: Updated my answer to try to answer the additional questions. Thanks.